# Laravel 5.6 unable to access property of object

Tags: php, laravel-5

I currently have

```
object(QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPSalesItemLineDetail)#334 (17) {
  ["ServiceDate"]=>
  NULL
  ["TaxInclusiveAmt"]=>
  NULL
  ["DiscountRate"]=>
  NULL
  ["DiscountAmt"]=>
  NULL
  ["SalesItemLineDetailEx"]=>
  NULL
  ["ItemRef"]=>
  string(1) "5"
  ["ClassRef"]=>
  NULL
  ["UnitPrice"]=>
  string(3) "275"
  ["RatePercent"]=>
  NULL
  ["PriceLevelRef"]=>
  NULL
  ["MarkupInfo"]=>
  NULL
  ["Qty"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["UOMRef"]=>
  NULL
  ["ItemAccountRef"]=>
  string(2) "79"
  ["InventorySiteRef"]=>
  NULL
  ["TaxCodeRef"]=>
  string(3) "TAX"
  ["TaxClassificationRef"]=>
  NULL
}
```

This is part of a bigger dataset I get from an api call.
Currently I pull this up like this:

```
foreach ($invoice->Line as $fv_element) {
            $element = $fv_element->SalesItemLineDetail;
              var_dump ($element);
         }
```

The data shown above is from the var_dump of $element.

I'm trying to access the `["Qty"] =>  string(1) "1"` data.

This is what I've tried:

```
$element->Qty
```

This gives this error: "Trying to get property of non-object"
I then try this `$element['Qty']`
This gives me this error: "Cannot use object of type QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPSalesItemLineDetail as array"

I also tried a foreach on $element and $element->Qty.  That didn't work either.  Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in your foreach loop it must be a `$fv_element->SalesItemLineDetail` that is null so try to check it before you access the property:

```
foreach ($invoice->Line as $fv_element) 
{
    $element = $fv_element->SalesItemLineDetail;
    if($element)
        dd($element->Qty);
    else
         dd("SalesItemLineDetail is null");
 }
```

Comment: why does it work with the if statement but with out... like if I do this with out the if statement: print_r($element->Qty);  it doesn't work?

Comment: Becouse 
'$fv_element->SalesItemLineDetail;' sometimes is null and when it happens is not an object anymore